# Finding 'Corresponding generalized eigenvectors:'

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ and I have it solves to have an eigenvalue of $1$, with an eigenvector $(1,0,0)$. I looked on wolfram alpha and it says that it has 'Corresponding generalized eigenvectors' of $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,-1,1)$

How do I go about finding these?

Comment: The article on  wiki would be a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by naming your given matrix :

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

To find the eigenvalues of $A$, you must solve the equation : $\det(A-λI)=0$. So, we have :

$$\det(A-λΙ)=0\Rightarrow \Bigg| \begin{matrix} 1-λ & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1-λ & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1-λ\end{matrix} \Bigg| = 0 \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow -(λ-1)^3=0 \Leftrightarrow λ =1$$

Note that your eigenvalue $λ_{1,2,3}=λ_1=1$ is of multiplicity $3$.

Now, to find the eigenvectors, you must solve the system : $(A-λ_1I)x=0$.

So :

$$(A-λ_1I)x=0 \Rightarrow (A-I)x=0 \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases} x_2 +x_3=0 \\ x_3=0 \end{cases}$$

This is something to be expected, as having an eigenvalue of multiplicty of $3$ while being the only one, should yield you $3$ different eigenvectors. You can observe that $x_2=x_3=0$ but $x_1$ is undetermined. Note, that eigenvectors should **NOT** be entirely $0$ vectors and must be linearly independent, so you cannot just take $3$ different values for $x_1$. The fact that the equation $ 0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 =0 \Rightarrow 0x_1 =0$ can be hold $\forall x_1 \in \mathbb R$, enables you to get $1$ eigenvector for a random $x_1$.

Taking $x_1=1$, we get the eigenvector :

$$v_1= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

To get, now, the other $2$ eigenvectors, you need to go through the *Generalized Eigenvector* calculation, which for $v_2$ will go as solving the system :

$$(A-λ_1I)v_2 = v_1$$

where you will express $v_2$ with variables that you'll find through solving the system.

Can you now, solve this system and yield $v_2$ and then proceed correctly for $v_3$ ?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can I use these to find a matrix of change of basis?